Polling data from kafka topic giving exception
I am trying to poll data from a kafka topic- "topic-a". I am trying ot poll that using kafka consumer listener. I have provided the below details in the application.yaml file for kafka configuration.
Instead of providing the consumer topic name as topic-a, why are my logs showing a different consumer client id?
2024-07-10 01:58:04.912  INFO 32708 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=dv-topic-B-consumer-0, groupId=dv-topic-b-745fe865-09c7-432d-9480-a60dca1fea07].

I am not specifying any groupId and client id in my application.yaml, how is kafka getting those details?
Also, I am getting below error,
2024-07-10 01:58:03.616  WARN 32708 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Error registering AppInfo mbean
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.consumer:type=app-info,id=dv-mfcs-appointment-consumer-0
TIA

I was expecting to return data from my private topic to be displayed for further processing. I have given my topic details and it also requires a kafka family fiels which I do not know what it is.

We need to see your code how you use those properties. The InstanceAlreadyExistsException means that you have several consumers with the same clientId. That also looks like you have many different Kafka consumers in your application since their clientIds don't correlate with that error.
